# Switch to running screen session after logout?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I tried `screen -r` and this is what I get:

```
$ screen -r
There is a screen on:
    1877.pts-0.domain   (10/21/2014 05:17:52 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

How can I resume the listed screen?

Answer (score 2):

Detatch the old `screen` by adding `-d`:

```
$ screen -rd
```

Answer (score 1):

`screen -x` attaches to non-detached sessions.